# using uploaded text file's contents as parameter for new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm uploading a plain text file and I'd like to use the text within as the parameters for a new object. Here's my attempt so far, in views/scans/new.html.erb:

```
<h1>New scan</h1>

<%= form_for :file_upload, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
<p><%= f.file_field :raw %></p>
<p><%= f.submit "Upload" %></p>
<% end %>
```

raw is a text attribute of the scan model. This yields the error:

```
Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/scans/new"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I can tell from Google that I need to File.read() but I don't know where I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

in model

```
def raw= (file)
  File.open(file,"r") do |f|
    self.your_atrribute = f.readlines.join("")
  end 
end
```

Comment: This causes "no such file or directory" enoent error. I don't understand it.